# Group by two column with vice versa value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have tried to group by with two columns:

```
SELECT recipient_id, sender_id, count(*) FROM messengers WHERE recipient_id=41 OR sender_id=41 group by recipient_id, sender_id
```

The output will be as shown below:

[image]

How I can combine row 1 and row 2 as a row because recipient_id and sender_id have same value which is 40 and 41.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One trick you can use here is to `GROUP BY` the *smaller* of the two ID columns and the *greater* of the two ID columns:

```
SELECT LEAST(recipient_id, sender_id), GREATEST(recipient_id, sender_id), COUNT(*)
FROM messengers
WHERE recipient_id = 41 OR sender_id = 41
GROUP BY LEAST(recipient_id, sender_id), GREATEST(recipient_id, sender_id)
```

Comment: it looks good so far. I'll try to use it and let's wait others answer before I vote yours as accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: I have modified your answer to this

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM messengers ORDER BY id desc) as A WHERE recipient_id = 41 OR sender_id = 41 GROUP BY LEAST(recipient_id, sender_id), GREATEST(recipient_id, sender_id)`

but I'm getting trouble to convert this to Laravel query builder.

Comment: @Mr.Byte The ANSI 92 standard requires that columns which appear in the `SELECT` either also appear in the `GROUP BY` or are aggregates.  So you should not use `SELECT *` here.  You can ask a new question with your Laravel problem.